# Are friend functions inherited? and why would a base class FRIEND function work on a derived class object?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, friend, friend-function

```
class baseClass {
public:
  friend int friendFuncReturn(baseClass &obj) { return obj.baseInt; }
  baseClass(int x) : baseInt(x) {}
private:
  int baseInt;
};

class derivedClass : public baseClass {
public:
  derivedClass(int x, int y) : baseClass(x), derivedInt(y) {}
private:
  int derivedInt;
};
```

in the function `friend int friendFuncReturn(baseClass &obj) { return obj.baseInt; }`
I don't understand why would the friend function of the base class work for the derived class?
should not passing derived class obj. instead of a base class obj. tconsidered as error?
my question is why it works when i pass a derived class object to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are friend functions inherited?

No, friend functions are not inherited.

> Why would a base class function work on a derived class object?

Because friend function is using the data members available in `base class` only. Not the data members of `derived class`. Since `derived class` is a type of `base class` So, friend function is working fine. But note that here `derived class` instance is `sliced` and having information available only for `base class`.
`friend function` will report an error if you will try to access restricted members of `derived class`. e.g.

```
 int friendFuncReturn(baseClass &obj) { return ((derivedClass)obj).derivedInt; }
```

Comment: It doesn't slice, `friendFuncReturn` takes a reference. Slicing is when you *copy* into a base from a derived object

Comment: @Caleth It is the same here i.e. copying into a base class object(function parameter `baseClass &obj`) from a derived object(passed argument e.g. `derivedClass d; friendFuncReturn(d);`).

Comment: A `derivedClass` object bound to a `baseClass` reference is still the same object, it is not sliced. You can `static_cast<derivedClass&>` it back. The function has to be the same for all possible `baseClass` subtypes, because there's only one of it.

Comment: And specifically `baseClass &` is a reference, not a value. There is no copying

Comment: Can you provide any example in which I'm passing the instance of `derived` class to the `base` class and can't get the value of `derived` class instance back? Also please give me an example of `object slicing`.

Comment: `int friendFuncReturn(baseClass obj)` <- recieved by value, will slice derived objects. `obj` is only a `baseClass`, it isn't a `derivedClass`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, But since we are _Putting_ an instance of `derived class` in `base class` variable, So it is `object slicing` i.e. Information of `derived class` are not available in `base class` variable and hence we cannot access of `derived class` feature here(which is `object slicing`).

Answer (score 3):

**No**. You cannot inherited friend function in C++. It is strictly one-one relationship between two classes.

**C++ Standard, section 11.4/8**

> Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive.