# Why are friend functions "available" for derived classes only when using public inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, friend, friend-function

When a derived class inherits from a base class via public access, the question is the same as that in [Are friend functions inherited? and why would a base class FRIEND function work on a derived class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469715/are-friend-functions-inherited-and-why-would-a-base-class-friend-function-work) . However, if it inherits via protected or private access, there will be a visibility error.

When it inherits via public access, the accessibility of private members of A is the same as if inheriting via private access. What's the difference between them?

```cpp
class A {
private:
    int a;
    friend void f();
};

class B : private A {
};

void f() {
    B obj;
    int x = obj.a;
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As specified by the link, there is no friendship inheritance in C++, so `f` is not a friend of `B`, so `f` cannot access private base classes or members of `B`, so `f` cannot access `B::a` since it would need access to the private base class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are friend functions inherited? and why would a base class FRIEND function work on a derived class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469715/are-friend-functions-inherited-and-why-would-a-base-class-friend-function-work)

Comment: Obviously, if you derive privately from a class, external code will essentially not see that you derives from that class. Thus given that external code does not see that `B` derive from `A`, then why would you expect `f` to be able to see that. When you do not derive publicly from a class, there no IS-A relationship between those classes. By the way, whenever possible, it is preferable to replace private or protected inheritance by containment. You want to avoid tight coupling as much as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already pointed out in the answer linked above, friendship is not inherited. Thus, a friend of `A` is not also a friend of `B`. Having `B` inherit from `A` via `private` access means that all members of `A` are accessible as private members of `B` [[class.access.base]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#1). Since `f` is not a friend of `B`, it cannot access private members of `B` [[class.access]/1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access#1.1). Since `f` is not a friend of `B`, the base class `A` of `B` is also not accessible from `f` [[class.access.base]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#4). Since the base class `A` of `B` is not accessible from `f`, there's also no way you could get to the `A` subobject of a `B` (of which you could access the members) in `f` [[class.access.base]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#5)…

Comment: I'm confused that when inherits via `public` access, accessibility of `private` members of `A` is the same as inherits as `private` access, what's the differene between them?

Comment: If `A` is a `public` base class of `B`, then a `B &` can be implicitly converted to an `A &`, so `A::a` is accessable, as `foo` is a friend of `A`